# R: add prorated rowmeans and percent missing of selection as new variables to df

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, purrr

This is a bit of a compound problem...

I want to calculate the prorated means for a selection of variables. I also want to calculate the percentage of missing variables for the same selection.
That is, if `bhs_1:bhs4` was `1 2 3 NA` I would expect to see the prorated mean *m* = 2, and the percent missing = 0.25. I know `NCOL(x)` and `length(x)` will give me the length of `x`, however not sure how to wrap all this up to get my result.
I want to bind this to my df for later analysis. I have a solution that works, which is:
However, I want to this repeatedly so was after a more efficient solution than repeating this over and over again.
Additionally, I need to calculate the rowmean based on different variables based on time of administration (`protocol` is the time variable in the df below).
Specifically, I have data from two different protocols, where during protocol 1, variables `bhs_1:bhs_4` were collected, however, during protocol 2, variables `bhsSF_1:bhsSF_4` were collected.

And, yet another twist, I have a measure that is part mandatory and part optional.
Specifically, `msssi_1:mssi_4` are mandatory items, whereas `mssi_5:mssi8` are optional, dependent on the answers of the former.
That is, if a participant scores a certain number on the former, then continue administration of the latter, otherwise stop.
Therefore, scores really for these ones are the mean of the length of the selection (i.e., 8 variables), not the prorated means.
So `NA` are important, but they are sometimes more or less equivalent to zero, but not always as they may actually be `NA`! I  hope that makes sense...

A tidy solution would be preferable, however base version is also okay as I would like to make this a function one day because I need to be able to do this regularly.

```
df <- df %>%
    select(bhs_1:bhs_4) %>%
    rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    round(., digits = 2) %>%
    bind_cols(my_data, bhs_mean = .)
```

```
## this works to calculate the number missing from the selected variables
df %>%
    select(bhs_1:bhs_4) %>%
    apply(., MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
## just not sure how to bind this as a new variables based on the number of NAs
## divided by length of selection
## I now that NCOL(x) and length(x) will give me the number of rows in the selection, but how
## do I use this to calculate the percentage?
```

A minimal data set.

```r
structure(list(protocol = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA
), uci = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, NA), pa_1 = c(NA,
2L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA), pa_2 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA,
4L, NA, 5L, NA), pa_3 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA),
    pa_4 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, NA), dass_1 = c(1L,
    1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), dass_2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), dass_3 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA,
    NA, NA), dass_4 = c(1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, NA),
    bhsSF_1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA), bhsSF_2 = c(NA,
    3L, NA, 6L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA), bhsSF_3 = c(NA, 3L, NA,
    6L, NA, 3L, NA, 6L, NA), bhsSF_4 = c(NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA,
    3L, NA, 5L, NA), bhs_1 = c(5L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L, NA, 5L, NA,
    NA), bhs_2 = c(5L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 5L, NA, NA), bhs_3 = c(6L,
    NA, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA), bhs_4 = c(5L, NA, 1L, NA,
    0L, NA, 1L, NA, NA), mssi_1 = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L,
    2L, NA), mssi_2 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA),
    mssi_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA), mssi_4 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), mssi_5 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 2L,
    NA, NA, 3L, 2L, NA), mssi_6 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L,
    2L, NA), mssi_7 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    mssi_8 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))
```

**BONUS ROUND**

As I said, I will do this repeatedly, so wrapping this up in a function would be ideal. I have never written a function, so if you could show me if and how this could be done that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't able to understand your second para, could you please describe it with output. For the first query, you can use the below function which will calculate average, fill count:

```
CalculatorFun1<- function(df,protocol_Type){

  # protocol_Type: can take values 1/2 , based on your data
  varList<-c()
  df<-cbind("Row_number"=row.names(df),df) # adding row_number for merging the datasets
  df$Row_number<- as.character(df$Row_number)

  if(protocol_Type==1){
    varList= names(df)[grepl("bhs_",names(df))]
  } else if(protocol_Type==2){
    varList= names(df)[grepl("bhsSF_",names(df))]
  } else {
    stop("Enter correct value for protocol_Type")
  }

  temp<- df %>%
    select(varList) %>%
    mutate(Row_number=row.names(df),
           NAcnt=apply(., 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))),
           cnt=apply(., 1, function(x) length(x)),
           Fill_Prop=1-(NAcnt/cnt),
           Avrg=round(rowMeans(.,na.rm = T),2)
    ) %>% select(Row_number,NAcnt,cnt,Fill_Prop,Avrg)

  Final_df<-df %>% left_join(temp, by =c("Row_number"="Row_number"))

  return(Final_df)

}

#call function for a protocal type
df_out<-CalculatorFun1(df,protocol_Type = 2)
```